# ArUco in Eclipse Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I want to compile the augmented reality ArUco library, but this library documentation on the internet is too scarce and I am facing some problems. Could someone give me a little tutorial about how to compile it in the Eclipse? (could be another IDE)
I'm using the Ubuntu 12.10, Eclipse Juno. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the README file of the library, you will probably have to use  [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/). Open a terminal and install cmake and OpenCv (the requirements for the library) with `apt-get`. I don't know their exact package names in Ubuntu, but try the obvious `cmake` and `opencv`.  Once that is done, `cd` to the directory where you unpackaged the aruco library, and do the following:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make all
make install
```

You can change the installation prefix by using `cmake -i ..` or `ccmake` if it got installed too.  As for setting up the library in your IDE, just make a note of which directories the library files (binaries and headers) got installed to, and make sure those are in the compiler's search path.